# How can I change the color of events of certain day regarding to their activities?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

[image: Sample image]

So in this calendar, I want to change the color of event depending to their activities, so for example the long event should have a color green.

so this is the sample data i'm trying to get.

this is what I received from my backend.

```
  {
      'title': 'All Day Event very long title',
      'allDay': true,
      'start': new Date(2023, 1, 1),
      'end': new Date(2023, 1, 6),
      'event': 'regular'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Long Event',
      'start': new Date(2023, 1, 1),
      'end': new Date(2023, 1, 1),
      'event':'holiday',
    },
```

Front.js

```
<Calendar

    views={["day", "agenda", "work_week", "month"]}
    selectable
    localizer={localizer}
    defaultDate={new Date()}
    defaultView="month"
    events={eventsData}
    style={{ height: "95%" }}
    onSelectEvent={(event) => alert(event.title)}
    onSelectSlot={handleSelect}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can provide *color* and *bgcolor* attributes along with other properties on event object,
If this package doesn't support's it, Use Full calendar, You surely can do that on full calendar,

```
events={[
          {
            groupId: '2023-02-05',
            title: 'Full Time',
            allDay: true,
            backgroundColor: '#A685DB',
            textColor: 'white',
            borderColor: '#A685DB',
            start: '2023-02-05T12:00',
          },
          {
            groupId: '2023-02-05',
            title: 'KLB003',
            backgroundColor: '#E31BCF',
            textColor: 'white',
            borderColor: '#E31BCF',
            start: '2023-02-05T14:00',
          }]
```

Try supplying on this structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by handling `eventPropGetter` function provided by lib and returing your style that needs to be applied.

```
const eventPropGetter = (event) => {
    console.log("event", event.isLong);
    if (event.isLong) {
      return {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: "#f0ad4e",
          borderRadius: "0px",
          opacity: 0.8,
          color: "white",
          border: "none"
        }
      };
    }

    // Customize styles for short events
    return {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#5cb85c",
        borderRadius: "0px",
        opacity: 0.8,
        color: "white",
        border: "none"
      }
    };
  };
```

And then you only decide which event is shorter/longer by structuring like this,

```
export const events = [
  {
      'title': 'All Day Event very long title',
      'allDay': true,
      'start': new Date(2023, 1, 1),
      'end': new Date(2023, 1, 6),
      'event': 'regular',
      //one more key here
      'isLong': true
    },
    {
      'title': 'Long Event',
      'start': new Date(2023, 1, 1),
      'end': new Date(2023, 1, 1),
      'event':'holiday',
      //one more key here
      'isLong': false
    },

];
```